# Unittest tearDown() method depends on finished test

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

I write Selenium tests, and have a problem. Before each test I upload different files for every test, and after test is done, I want to remove these files from application even if test failed. There are two methods `setUp` and `tearDown`. They are called before and after every test, but how can I define which test was finished in the `tearDown` method? It is important for me, because after each test I want to remove different files from application, depending on the finished test.

I want something like:

```
def tearDown(self):
    if test1_is_finished():
       remove_test1_files
    if test2_is_finished():
       remove_test2_files
    # and so on
```

I am new to Python and Selenium tests, and maybe a better approach exists to do some job after after the test was finished, even if it failed.

Comment: If you need to do *different things* (`setUp`/`tearDown`) for each test, then shouldn't you do it in the tests themselves?

Comment: Thanks for answer, just a minute ago I have edited the question. I need to remove files even if test failed. Maybe tearDown cant solve my problem, but maybe another approach exists

Comment: *They are called before and after every test* i believe they are only called when once: before and after *all* tests in that file are run

Comment: @TimCastelijns no, that's `setUpClass`/`setUpModule` and `tearDownClass`/`tearDownModule`.

Comment: Could you just split the test cases into separate classes with their own `setUp`/`tearDown`? If `setUp` is always the same, you could inherit it from some base class/mix-in.

Comment: Hi  Tim Castelijn, I've checked, they are called after each test in a file. If I had non static method, that will be called only before and after all tests in the file, it will solve my problem. Not by the best way, but I can upload all my files before the tests and remove all of them after all tests. But I found only static method that works like that

Comment: jonrsharpe, I cant split them, because they all do very similar work, they run the scripts, which are stored  in files, and verify execution. 1 file with script and 1 file with results for every test. So creating separate class for every test is not best solution for my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `setUp` method (to be run before every test), create a list, `to_be_removed`:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.to_be_removed = []
```

In each unit test, append the filenames to `to_be_removed`:

```
def test1(self):
    ...
    self.to_be_removed.append(filename)
```

Then, in `tearDown`, remove all files listed in `to_be_removed`:

```
def tearDown(self):
    for filename in self.to_be_removed:
        os.unlink(filename)
```

This way, you can handle all `tearDown`s the same way.